# Issue with R - Shiny command runGitHub()

Tags: r, github, shiny

Is there any restriction on running the runGitHub() command from the R console for private repos on GitHub. The command was working when the repo was "Public", but recently had to convert it to "Private" post which runGitHub doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas?

Comment: This earlier response seems to be specific to install_github(). My query is around runGitHub(). Nevertheless generated an auth token and tried passing it along i.e. > runGitHub('DPD-Application','togyjose',auth_token = "a5cee9177c1fff6d9ea0d48d954f364bceaf8365")  >>> still not working >>> 
Downloading https://github.com/togyjose/DPD-Application/archive/master.tar.gz
Error in utils::download.file(url, method = method, ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'https://github.com/togyjose/DPD-Application/archive/master.tar.gz'

Comment: Update your post with codes you have tried, error outputs, add more detail and vote to re-open.